# Evap code and the gas cap

Tags: rust, evap

I have a 2008 Jeep Liberty that has had the check engine light come on many times over the years for P0456 Evap leak.  The problem seems to be rust forming where the gas cap gets placed.  I remove the rust, throw some grease on it, and it clears the code for a while, this last time it lasted 8 months.  It's not an intermitted thing, as I've left the check engine light on for 6+ months before having to deal with it for inspections.  Removing the rust always seems to clear the code.  Rust eventually begins to form again after removing and applying grease.  I've tried painting it, but the paint eventually comes off and rust forms again.  I live in an area that gets lots of precipitation, snow, and salt spread on the roads.

What would work good at stopping the rust here?  An enamel spray? Epoxy?  I need something that will bond well with the iron but also can tolerate some friction.

Comment: You might try some rust converter like POR-15. If you do use something like that, you'll want to let it completely dry before putting the cap back on. This stuff will bond whatever touches against it to whatever metal you put it on. It should, however stand up to the friction, and it will definitely solve the rust issue.

Comment: Are you sure the rust is the issue?  The gas tank needs to be airtight.  Is the gasket on the gas cap in good shape? Really the place the gasket lands is what matters.

Comment: @Harper-ReinstateMonica "The place where the gasket lands"...is the place that is rusting.

Comment: @Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2 You should make this an answer. The metal had become pitted from regular rusting and removal of rust to the point where the check engine light would not go off when removing the rust.  The POR-15 gave it a nice smooth surface again and cleared the evap leak code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might try some rust converter like POR-15. If you do use something like that, you'll want to let it completely dry before putting the cap back on. This stuff will bond whatever touches against it to whatever metal you put it on. It should, however stand up to the friction, and it will definitely solve the rust issue.